# {Binding DataContext.foo} vs {Binding foo} Difference

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datacontext

I thought `{Binding DataContext.foo}` and `{Binding foo}` were identical until I came across an issue binding a selection changed event from a `ComboBox` to a command in my ViewModel.

I was doing it like so...

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
     <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

Using `DataContext.TestCommand` works while just specifying `TestCommand` appears to fail. I've never encountered a difference between the two can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're binding to two subtly different things:

`"Binding DataContext.TestCommand"` is binding to the `TestCommand` property of the `Datacontext` (presumably the context defines that property) of your `Page`.

`"Binding TestCommand"` is binding to the `TestCommand` property of the `Page` itself, which in this case probably doesn't exist, which is why it doesn't work.

There's a neat program called WPF Snoop that you can use to inspect the bindings whilst things are running (often helps me make sense of things when I'm, stuck).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Is there a way to say I want you to bind to the already established datacontext of the page or is that basically what the DataContext. syntax is?

Comment: Things like this have driven me nuts on occasion =D

Answer (score 2):

Almost each element in visual tree (*View*) is linked to the data layer (*ViewModel*) per `DataContext` property. Of course the data layer tree is much more simpler because most controls just inherit from their parent.

By default a `Binding` is looking for the `Path` in data layer. But if you specify a `RelativeSource` (like `RelativeSource.Self` or with `AncestorType`) or an `ElementName` the `Binding` switches to visual layer and searches in controls for the bound property. With `DataContext` you can go back to data layer.